# Max Number of Changeset allowed in a Simple OData client batch Call

Tags: c#, changeset

I'm trying to make a batch call which can include multiple changeset (i.e. multiple PUT/POST calls), When I create a batch with more than 10 changesets in a batch then it throws me error "Bad Request". It is working fine with less than 10 changesets. So I'm wondering is this the max limit of ODataBatch client, if no then is there any way to increase this limit?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: If you own the end point you might want to check the logs on why the batch request failed. A limitation of 10 requests is highly unlikely.

Comment: Hi @jegtugado Thanks for your comment, I'm getting Bad Request as response with the error message  "Malformed URI literal syntax", I have verified the URLs for both batch calls (with less 10 operations and with more than 10 operation ) there is no difference in URLs.

Comment: I'm thinking about the logs on the end point server and not the response from the end point. If it really is a malformed URI literal syntax, won't you be able to catch that in your server's logs? That is only if you have access to those, having more than 1 thing to look at can help you get a better perspective on the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @jegtugado for the suggestion , I found the issue, the issue was that value of a key was set up wrong after 9 line Items. It is working now :)